# Is it possible to use common AuthorizedKeysFile for a group of users without disabling StrictMode in sshd_config?

Tags: ssh, permissions, file-permissions, public-key

```
# rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64
```

I want to use a common `AuthorizedKeysFile` in `sshd` for multiple users on my server. For that, I added:

```
Match Group my-secret-group
        AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/my-secret-group/common_authorized_keys
```

to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and then added all those users to group `my-secret-group`.

`sshd` restarted fine, but that didn't allow me to log into accounts of the users in `my-secret-group` with a public key. However, when I set `StrictModes no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, it finally worked. I'm concerned that I shouldn't use `StrictModes no`, but I'm not sure what files should have what permissions for this setup to work. Currently, I have:

```
root:/etc/ssh/# ls -al my-secret-group/{.,common_authorized_keys}
-rw-r----- 1 root my-secret-group 2776 Nov  3 07:41 my-secret-group/common_authorized_keys

my-secret-group/.:
total 16
drwxrwx---  2 root my-secret-group   74 Nov  4 10:02 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root            4096 Nov  4 10:33 ..
-rw-r-----  1 root my-secret-group 2776 Nov  3 07:41 common_authorized_keys
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root            419 Nov  4 09:23 install_ssh_keys
-rw-r--r--  1 root root            274 Nov  3 07:47 README.md
```

Can I adjust permissions somehow so I don't have to set `StrictModes no`? I tried various combinations, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AuthorizedKeysCommand` instead to get the authorized keys. This command does not need to confirm to these requirements (but you need to make sure the command is sane). For example

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/cat /etc/ssh/my-secret-group/common_authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root
# or whatever reasonable user with access to this file
```

should do the job.

Comment: Actually, I just tested it again and `AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/cat /path/to/file` is not correct either. `sshd` treats the whole line `/usr/bin/cat /path/to/file` as the name of a command, I can see that from an error message in `/var/log/secure` in my system. I had to create a script that calls `cat /path/to/file` and add `AuthorizedKeysCommand /path/to/script` to `sshd_config`.